# Associating an array with an object in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I want to associate an array of objects with another object without specifying an id while I'm building the array. I'm pretty sure I've seen this done before, but can't find it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  has_many :job_groups
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :job_group
end

class JobGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :jobs
end
```

Company.rb

```
def self.user_links(user)
  job_group = JobGroup.create(user_id: user.id)
  user.companies.each do |c|
    links = c.find_links
    job_group << links
  end
end
```

Links comes back as a collection of links and I want to associate it to a job group.

I get a NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you really want but clearly you can't `push` or `<<` an object to an object(in this case `job_group`). You can only push object to array.

I assume you need another attribute of type Array in `job_group` model so you can associate `links` to it eg `job_group.links << links`.

Hope it helps